# Is it possible to programatically create labels in AutoCad?

Tags: label, autocad, cad

Our engineering department wastes a great amount of time reviewing drawings for errors. The majority of these problems involve human errors in labeling (ie. two rooms have the name `01-01-00-RM`). Our IT department has come up with a partial solution by automation the room names. However, the engineers still have to type this into AutoCAD.

Is there any way to create labels in AutoCAD based on another file (ie. an Excel/CSV document)? Ideally, one would create a group in a layer and enforce that all elements be unique, then have them retrieve their values from a document.

**EDIT**

Some screenshots of the labels. Note, for company reasons, I can't put full PDF screenshots up.

First image showing compact label next to a camera. This was on a floor plan overlay.

[image]

Second image showing the full lable next to a camera. This was in the block diagram

[image]

Comment: Do all your labels look the same? We have managed the same issue in our eng. department with a combination of .net code and a dynamic block - we have an AutoCad custom function with 3 parameters - point(ing to), point(ing to label), label text. Very fast to use and fast even to modify because the label is a dynamic block. If you solve it like that you need only the "Insert block" and "prompt for points" functionality.

Comment: Can't reliably answer the question *look the same?* The unique internal labels we give them can be anything (ie. MAC Address values). What we map those two, however, (which will be what the customer sees) will have a predefined syntax, sort of like `[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[A-Z][A-Z]`

Comment: I ask about the graphical representation of "the box with the arrow" or the "thing" which indicates the label. Of course there can be none. The text can be anything. If you give me a link to a screenshot with an example label I will be able to help you with an accurate answer (aka solution)

Comment: Ok. When I am ready with the sample I will paste it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, there some different paths:

- Lisp: very common on AutoCAD environment and allow some basic (and not so basic) automations.
- VBA/COM: can be used from inside AutoCAD or by external process, just need to CreateObject("Application.AutoCAD") and program the steps
- .NET or C++: in-process automation that allow powerful customization, up to a major remodeling of AutoCAD.

So, depending on your expertise, you may choose different approaches. It may also combine with batch processing via AutoCAD Console.

Find more at http://www.autodesk.com/developautocad and at the blog http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad

Answer (score 0):

If the labels were blocks with attributes then you could use the ATTOUT and ATTIN commands in Express tools to export / import them in to/out of Excel. Watch for cell formatting in Excel - eg. numbers like `1/2` turn into dates if you leave the formatting as "General".

Programmatically this is reasonably trivial **if the data is structured**. An AutoCAD drawing is actually a hierarchical object database so everything in it is addressable, finding it is often the hardest part. If you have an AutoCAD installation handy, have a look into a drawing with [MGDDBG](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/04/dwg-debugger-mgddbg-app-for-autocad-20122013.html) to get an idea of the database structure.